# How definition ID in JAXB in java?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two class(layer,image) this class have ID ,each ID is unique ID (ID must not repeated),when I used JAXB to parser my class to XML was noted  ID is repeated How I can not allow  insert same ID.

Layer class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Project")
public class Layer {
    private String id;
    private Image[] images;
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="images")
    public Image[] getImages() {
       return images;
    }

    public void setImages(Image[] images) {
       this.images = images;
    }
}
```

image class:

```
public class Image {
   private String id;
   @XmlID
   @XmlAttribute(name="id")
     public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
     public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The result XML is:

```
<project>
 <layer id="1">//I don't want repeated ID layer 
   <images id="1">// I don't want repeated ID in in same layer tag
    </images>
   <images id="1">
    </images>
 </layer>
 <layer id="1">//here not 2 not 1, if code understand this is ID that mean give me error or massage 
   <images id="1">
    </images>
   <images id="1">
    </images>
 </layer>
</project>
```

Comment: If you serialize XML, then you generate ids and it is responsibility of your code to set ids correctly, jaxb will not do it for you.

Comment: that mean each time I create method for get last id from xml after that insert id , and how can put all roles same  maxOccurs="1" or ..

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Share the code where you set it.

Comment: I have Data base XMl this Database have ID but I search About keyword  In JAXB to but rolls to my xml same roll which put to schema xml same "maxOccurs = 1 , that mine allow to my tag reputed one time" but IN JAXB I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JAXB the `@XmlID` annotation is not used to enforce uniqueness.  It just means that the mapped field/property corresponds to the `xs:ID` type.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

**Note:**

If you generated an XML Schema from your model and set that on the `Unmarshaller` to enable validation (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html), then that would give validation errors if there was more than one node of type `xs:ID` in a document with the same value.